# Openlayers 3 custom Polygon feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to create a custom `Polygon` style for my layer style.

I receive some information about position, orientation and age for a number of objects and I want to represent those as **zoom independent** (like using `Icons` or `RegularShapes`) isosceles triangles, pointing at an angle and color-coded according to age.

I have a good idea of the color-coding and rotation part, but I'm stumped at creating an isosceles triangle using the style objects provided by OpenLayers.

This is what I have so far:

```
style = [new ol.style.Style({
    geometry: function(feature) {
        return new ol.geom.Polygon([[
            [0, 0],
            [2, 0],
            [1, 3]
        ]]);
    },
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#000'}) //black right now
})]
```

Comment: Maybe this will help, although it handles circles instead of polygons: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58570/openlayers-make-polygons-not-zoom

Comment: The problem is exactly that OpenLayers only provides `Circle`, `Icon` and `RegularShape` as "point" styles. I need to define a custom shape that doesn't fit into any of these types.

Answer (score 2):

this will create a triangle

```
new ol.style.Style({
image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
  color: 'red'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: 'black', 
  width: 2
  }),
  points: 3,
  radius: 10,
  rotation: Math.PI / 4,
  angle: 0
  })
})
```

for more symbols check this example [regular shapes example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/regularshape.html)

you can always use extrenal images to style your points as an alternative.
something like this should work if this is your case

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: 'data/icon.png'
  }))
});
```

Comment: `RegularShape` only allows for regular polygons/stars (each side the same size), I need an isosceles triangle. The second approach is what I have right now, but I need to change it because I need to represent my features with arbitrary colors, and this is infeasible using image `Icons`.

Comment: isosceles triangle is a regural shape. isnt it? No matter the title the sample I provide is an isosceles triangle. Did you try it?

Comment: As you can see in the example you provided (which has similar code to what you posted), thar code generates an _equilateral_ triangle.

Comment: equilateral triangle is isosceled as well in terms of geometry. So now its clear, you strictly want to produce isosceled triagles and not equilateral. As far as I know ol3 doesnt provide a direct way to do your job. The code snip you allready use, seems to me  the only way. What is wrong with it?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for my geometrical imprecision ;) The problem with the snippet I posted is that Geometries (in Styles at least) represent actual physical coordinates, so a polygon style will represent an actual physical area instead a point.

Comment: Dont worry about it, I am just too Pythagoras addictive. A last though is to use `ol.style.Text` and then use Unicode Characters in the Geometric Shapes. A list of them may be found here -->http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/list.htm you can just copy-paste them. If any these symbols feet your needs you can play with fill/stroke color and rotation. I have made a feedle to make your life easier -->http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/454f3dgo/

Comment: That is actually a great idea, since I can even make my own vector fonts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no probs amigo. good luck

Comment: There's just one problem with this... `style.Text`doesn't have a `rotateWithView` property so I can't keep my features pointing to where I want if I rotate the map...

Comment: For the problem you mentioned, The only way out I may think is to listen for the `change:rotation` event and apply it to the vector source. Check the fiddle -->http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/454f3dgo/ I have updated it

Comment: I was afraid of having to iterate over 100k~ points to update their rotation every tick so I just hacked OL's source code to add a `rotateWithView` property to `style.Text`. This way the rotation is compensated at render time.

Comment: That was the first thing I though. But then you have to apply changes its time ol3 updates its version. Maybe you should make a ticket and ask them to apply this change. It will be usefull for everyone

Comment: I'm kinda new to the git flow, I had posted an issue on the OL git but they asked me to remove it since it was a "usability" question. What is the proper channel to submit feature requests?